# Spreading sequence in DSSS

Tags: digital-communications

In DSSS, the spreading sequence is known only to the receiver and the transmitter. But for example, if we consider a spreading sequence built around a certain signal known only to the receiver and not to the transmitter. On reception, the signal is a key making it possible to decode the spread message with the constructed spreading sequence. Moreover, if an intruder intercepts the spreading sequence, he will not be able to decode the message since the spreading sequence does not make it possible to find the original message.

Do you think this gives a secure system for DSSS?

Comment: "a spreading sequence built around a certain signal" -- what does that mean?

Comment: Welcome to SE.SP!  This question needs much more information  for us to help out. What is your intent?  If the transmitter doesn't know the spreading sequence, how can it compose the signal to transmit to the receiver? But there's some ambiguity in your `a spreading sequence built around a certain signal known only to the receiver and not to the transmitter` so I'm not clear what you mean (as MBaz also points out). Please [edit your question](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/posts/83709/edit) with more of these details and ping me and I can reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

> the spreading sequence is known only to the receiver and the transmitter.

is only *necessarily* known to the receiver and the transmitter. There's nothing that says it needs to be a secret. In fact, it's nearly impossible to keep it a secret.

> On reception, the signal is a key making it possible to decode the spread message with the constructed spreading sequence

That signal would simply be called "spreading sequence": There's nothing special about it.

> Moreover, if an intruder intercepts the spreading sequence, he will not be able to decode the message since the spreading sequence does not make it possible to find the original message.

That is self-contradictory. If the receiver is able to despread using the sequence, then anyone else can, as well.

I think you're trying to somehow imagine secrecy where there is none: If I know the despreading sequence, I can despread, no matter how the sequence was calculated.

If I can see a bit of transmission using a short spreading sequence, then autocorrelation properties allow me to reconstruct the spreading sequence very well.

In other words, there's no free lunch. If you need to negotiate a key, you will negotiate a key, for example through Diffie-Hellman. The fact that this key is used to derive a spreading sequence really doesn't help. Spreading is not cryptography!

There *is* the field of *physical layer security*, where the secrecy lies in the physical realization of the two-way channel between transmitter and receiver. But be aware that for practical communication scenarios (indoor, factory automation), typical secrecy rates are counted in bits per minute. You can't exchange more bits than the secrecy rate without an eavesdropper being able to recover the message. There's really few use cases where this competes with classical cryptography.